# Run-time Error '6' Overflow when storing date in var

Tags: excel, vba

I am iterating through dates in a loop to execute different snippets of code.The following piece of code in the loop gives me a

> runtime error '6' Overflow

when assigning the cell's value to `dateClaim`:

```
Dim dateClaim As Date
Dim rngDateClaimeMade As Range

Set rngDateClaimeMade = dfensCSheet.Range("AC7") 'AC contains dates in format dd.mm.yyyy

dateClaim = rngDateClaimeMade.value
dateClaimMonth = Format(Month(dateClaim), "00")
dateClaimYear = Year(dateClaim)
```

Any ideas/ help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual cell value when the error occurs?

Comment: What is `Debug.Print rngDateClaimeMade.value`? And are the values in AC7 real numeric date values or are they text looking like a date? Check also what `Debug.Print  rngDateClaimeMade.NumberFormat` is.

Comment: Please, try `dateClaim = CDate(dfensCSheet.Range("AC7").value)`. This will convert it in `Date`, even if is text formatted...

Comment: In the immediate window, type `?rngDateClaimeMade.value2 <enter>` and report what it shows.  Note that `value2` should return just a number with no formatting, if there is really a date present.

Comment: @FaneDuru While an explicit conversion (like you suggest) is always good, there will be an implicit type conversion from string to date anyway if it possible. If it is not possible making it explicit won't change anything.

Comment: @FaneDuru Also, if the data is of the wrong type, I would expect a Type Mismatch error.  Usually an overflow error would imply a date later than `12/31/9999` and perhaps showing `######` in the date-formatted cell.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I am not so sure... It may switch the day with month, if the date string is not in the standard format according to localization. It will return an error only for strings not possible to be converted to a date. Of course, `CDate("Test")` will return such an error. But even such a conversion for an empty cell will not return an error. It will return "00:00:00", but not an error. Even `12/31/9999` will be converted in a date without erroring. It is only a matter of testing in this way...

Comment: @FaneDuru I would be curious, in your testing, what you entered in the cell to produce an "overflow" error in his code.

Comment: `I am iterating through dates in a loop to execute different snippets of code.` I do not see a loop? Debug the code if there is a loop and check which cell is giving the error and what is the value of that cell.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I could never reproduce such an error (Excel 2016 Pro). I only read about such errors when a big number in a cell formatted as Date, displaying "##############", should raise such an error, but never in my case. Only `Type mismatch` for everything not possible to be converted in Date. Could you reproduce the error with `12/31/9999`, or something else? If yes, what Excel version do you use?

Comment: @FaneDuru Enter a number `=>  2,958,466` **AND** format the cell as a date.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld:  Yes, I could reproduce the error now! Happy I learned something... :)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ?rngDateClaimeMade.value2 <enter> gives back a number 6687589

Comment: That is not a valid date.  Dates are stored as numbers (days since 1/1/1900) and the highest allowable date is `12/31/9999` which would return a vlaue of `2,958,465`.  What is stored in that cell is clearly not a number within the allowable date range, hence your overflow error.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ `Debug.Print rngDateClaimeMade.value` gives back 24.12.2020 while `Debug.Print  rngDateClaimeMade.NumberFormat`shows [$-101040A]dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks very much, Ron. Is there an easy way to convert my dates into something processable? I do have dd.mm.yyy

Comment: Especially if all of your dates are text strings, you can convert by using the vba `DateSerial` function after splitting the date on the `.` dot. However, if some of your dates are real dates, and others are strings, it is likely that your data import process needs to be fixed so that all of the dates get imported as real dates. Else the one's that are real dates were probably converted incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that looks like `24.12.2020` is a text not a date in that cell and therefore it cannot be converted automatically.

If your dates are always in this format `dd.mm.yyyy` you can convert it like below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim TextDate As String   ' this is a text looking like a date (but is not a date just a string)
    TextDate = "24.12.2020"   ' instead read your cell value here
    
    ' test if the string has a format that we can convert
    If Not TextDate Like "??.??.????" Then
        MsgBox "Date was not in expected format dd.mm.yyyy"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' split text into 3 parts by dot as delimiter
    Dim SplitDate() As String
    SplitDate = Split(TextDate, ".")
    
    ' reorder the 3 parts to make a real numeric date
    Dim NumericDate As Date
    NumericDate = DateSerial(SplitDate(2), SplitDate(1), SplitDate(0))
    
    ' this numeric date is now a real date that can be formatted as desired
    Debug.Print Format$(NumericDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") 'returns 2020-12-24
End Sub
```

You can then use

```
Dim dateClaim As Date
dateClaim = DateSerial(SplitDate(2), SplitDate(1), SplitDate(0))

Dim dateClaimMonth As String
dateClaimMonth = Format$(dateClaim , "mm")

Dim dateClaimYear As String
dateClaimYear = Format$(dateClaim , "yyyy")
```

if you need month and year as text! If you need them numeric don't use `Format$()`!

Comment: Thank you very much. This nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

VBA cannot convert text dates with dots directly. So try:

```vb
dateClaim = DateValue(Replace(rngDateClaimeMade.Value, ".", "/"))
dateClaimMonth = Month(dateClaim)
dateClaimYear = Year(dateClaim)
```

Apply the format **00** where the month is to be displayed.

Comment: `VBA cannot convert text dates with dots directly` - that is not true. `CDate()`, which is implicitly called, uses the current locale's date separators.